# How do I delete a message in ActiveMQ using ZFW2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, activemq-classic, zend-queue

I am using ZendQueue component https://github.com/zendframework/ZendQueue.
After I read my messages, I try to delete them.
I am using the `Queue` object and the `Activemq` adapter.
I am connecting ok, as I am able to get the data I publish.  The code is below:

```
$message_iterator = $queue->receive(50,50);
foreach($message_iterator as $MessageObject){
     do_somthing($MessageObject->body);
     $queue->getAdapter()->deleteMessage($MessageObject);
}
```

$queue is `\ZendQueue\Queue`
$MessageObject is `\ZendQueue\Message`
adapter is `ZendQueue\Adapter\Activemq`

Comment: .. and your error/problem/error log/debug output/activemq log/etc  is what?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs. After long research I found out that to delete a message u need to use the messagwe id AND be on the same session.
For It was disconnecting between read and delete. Once that was fixed, all went well.